# script to call other php page not working

Tags: javascript

need help, button not working, my report generator button which is from my main page is not calling the report.php page, in Chrome, i've checked the network tab under developer tools and im not getting any activity/response when i click the report generator button, below is my main php page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#RetrieveList").on('click',function() {
                var xid = $('#XiD').val();
                var date = $('#Date').val();
                $.post('retrieve_test.php',{xid:xid, date:date}, function(data){
                $("#results").html(data);
                });
                return false;
            });

            $("#DeletefromDB").click(function() {
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))
                var id = $('input[name=checkbox]:checked').map(function()
                    {
                        return $(this).val();
                    }).get();
                $.post('delete_test.php',{id:id}, function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
                });

                return false;
            });                 
            });

            $("#Report").on('click',function() {
            var date = $('#Date').val();
                $.post('report.php',{date:date}, function(data){
                $("#results").html(data);
                });
                return false;
            });

    </script>

        <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">

              <table width="741" border="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="9" align="center" style="font-size:14px" scope="col">Xid, Name:<span>
                    <select name="XiD" id="XiD">

                      <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
                      <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
                      <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
                    </select>
                  </span><span style="font-size:14px">
                  <label for="date">Date:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="Date" id="Date" size="8"/>
                  </span></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="9" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="9" scope="col">
                    <div align="center">
                      <input name="action" type="button" id="RetrieveList" value="Retrieve List" />
                      <input name="action" type="button" id="DeletefromDB" value="Delete from DB" />
                      <input name="Clear" type="reset" id="Clear" value="Clear" onClick="window.location.reload()" />
                  <input name="action" type="button" id="Report" value="Report Generator" />
                    </div>
                    <label for="Clear"></label>
                    <div align="center"></div></th>
                </tr>

              </table>
              </form>
            <div id="results">
            </div>
```

while here is my report.php page code:

```
<?php
    require 'include/DB_Open.php';

    $date = $_POST['date'];

    $sql="SELECT trouble_type_priority, category_1, category_2, status, COUNT (*) AS Total 
               FROM tbl_main 
               WHERE resolved_date = '$date'
               GROUP BY trouble_type_priority, category_1, category_2, status";

    $myData = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<table width='auto' cellpadding='1px' cellspacing='0px' border=1 align='center'>
    <tr>
        <th colspan='3' align='center'>Ticket Bucket</th>
        <th colspan='3' align='center'>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width='auto' align='center'>Severity</th>
        <th width='auto' align='center'>Category 2</th>
        <th width='auto' align='center'>Category 3</th>
        <th width='auto' align='center'>Resolved</th>
        <th width='auto' align='center'>Re-assigned</th>
        <th width='auto' align='center'>Grand Total</th>
    </tr>";

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) 
    {
    echo"<tr>"; 

    echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['trouble_type_priority'] . "</td>"; 
    echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['category_1'] . "</td>"; 
    echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['category_2'] . "</td>"; 
    echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['status'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</table>"; 


    include 'include/DB_Close.php';
    ?>
```

Comment: do you get an js error or smth. else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the code you have for setting the `onclick` event for the Report button is outside of the `$(document).ready(...)` function. Right now, your javascript will execute before the rest of the page is ready and at that point there will be no Report button to add the event to it.

I think, this may be the issue. Try moving the `$("#Report").on('click', ...)` into the `$(document).ready(...)` callback function.

Comment: nice eye...how can i not see that...i think im too tired already...anyways...thanks for the assist...

Answer (score 0):

I can't format comments but to get more information about what's going on could you console.log some things: And not sure if this helps but put the date property in quotes: {'date':date}

```
        console.log("adding click handler to:",$("#Report"));
        $("#Report").on('click',function() {
           console.log("date will be:",$('#Date').val());
           var date = $('#Date').val();
            $.post('report.php',{'date':date}, function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });
```